# Magento 2 : Get current_category is cached and shows wrong IDs on category submenu

Tags: magento2, category, full-page-cache

I have created a module to avoid an objectManager. In this I have

> ```
> public function getCurrentCategory()
> {        
>     return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
> }
> ```

On my phtml file I call

```
$myBlock->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
```

I have full page cache enabled and created a custom submenu on the left sidebar. I want to make the font of the current category bold.

Everything works fine except when I click on an other category the category ID is not refreshed and the visited category remains selected until I manually clean the cache. How can I avoid caching from my function and make sure that each time the getCurrentCategory is refreshed properly?

Comment: this is due to your block is cached. you might have to hole punching

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below way :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager $cacheManager
) {
    $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
}
public function getCurrentCategory()
{        
    $this->cacheManager->flush($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());
   $this->cacheManager->clean($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());

    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}
```

To put flush and clean cache in your code.

**hope its work for you**

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. Thanks for your effort though

Comment: have another option goto menu layout and add menu block as cachable="false"

Comment: I tried cacheable="false" but still no result. Maybe it does not work out of the design update within the category.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this method to your block class

```
public function getCacheKey()
{
    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $catId = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    return "CATEGORY_SUBMENU_{$catId}_STORE_{$storeId}";
}
```

That will ensure every category gets an unique cached block instance. The point is that no 2 categories can have the same block in cache that's why we add category id and store id to the cache key.

Additionally you should add this method:

```
protected function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return 86400;
}
```

This will set cache lifetime of the block to 1 day (86400 seconds). Adjust as needed.

Not sure if this will fix your issue but it's worth trying :) I've had similar issues before and this has solved them most of the time.

Remember that disabling cache, flushing the cache constantly and `cacheable="false"` is never the solution.

Comment: What do you do with the cache key returned?

Comment: @AdamLavery nothing. You just implement this method into your block class and let Magento handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but nothing doing. Added that to block file, cleaned & flushed cache but the function is never called (running a live debug session). We're using the related block to display other products in the same category. Some products are in two categories. After clearing cache and selecting the product from each category once it works fine, but select from the first category again and $registry->registry('current_category') returns null. Hence we fall back the first category the product belongs to.